# How can I use a while loop to run through several functions in python

Tags: python, function, while-loop, iteration

I have two functions, one checks if you would like to add any items to a dictionary, and then checks what the value of that item is and saves that data to a file. If you are done adding new items to the dictionary it moves to the next function that checks if you would like to change the value of any currently existing items. If everything is good to go you can command the program to exit.

My problem is creating the while loop and to make it call the first function and run it but when you have no more items to add I need it to call the next function and makes sure you don't need to change any values of currently existing items. And then when the exit command is put in it exits the while loop and the program quits. I can't figure out how to make the while loop determine the first function is over and to call the next one.

I had made the program work properly by using recurrence and no while loop. But somebody told me that was sloppy. Also I made it work when I built the functions inside the while loop, but they told me that was sloppy too. So I am trying to make the while loop after the functions are built and call for the functions inside of it. Thanks in advance and hopefully my question is clear.

```
    # current dictionary 
    itemNames = {}

    # checks if you want to add to your dictionary
    def addToDictionary():      
        checkIF_newItems = raw_input("Add new item? 'YES' or 'NO' \n ").upper()
        if checkIF_newItems.startswith("Y"):
            newItems = raw_input("What type of item would you like to add today? \n")
            newItems_Name = raw_input("What is the value of your new item? \n")
            itemNames[newItems] = newItems_Name
            return True
        elif 'PRINT' in checkIF_newItems:
            print "These are your current items. \n\n"
            return True
        elif checkIF_newItems.startswith("N"):
            print("OKAY")
            exit()
        elif 'Exit' in checkIF_newItems:
            exit()  

    # checks if you want to edit your current dictionary
    def check_forChanges():
        #checks user intent and if YES prints current keys
        checkIf = raw_input("Change item value? 'YES' 'NO' 'EXIT' 'ADD' 'PRINT' \n").upper()
        print("\n")

        if checkIf.startswith("Y"):
            for i in itemNames.keys():
                print i
            print("\n") 
            #finds what key to access and ask for its new value
            itemChoice = raw_input("what item would you like to change the value of? \n")
            return True

            if itemChoice in itemNames.keys():
                newName = raw_input("What is the new value? \n")
                itemNames[itemChoice] = newName
                print("You've changed your " + itemChoice + "'s value to " + newName + ".")
                return True
            print('\n')
            return True 

        #if NO then checks to exit
        elif checkIf.startswith("N"):
            CLOSE = raw_input("OKAY then, would you like to exit? ").upper()

            if CLOSE.startswith('Y'):
                exit()
                return False

            elif EXIT.startswith('N'):
                check_forChanges()

            elif EXIT is 'print':
                for i in itemNames:
                    print i 
                    return True

        # goes back to first function
        elif 'ADD' in checkIf:
            addToDictionary()
            return True

        #prints current values
        elif 'PRINT' in checkIf:
            for i in itemNames.values():
                print i 
                return True

        elif 'EXIT' in checkIf:
            exit()
            return False

    # main routine
    validIntro = False
    while not validIntro:
        addToDictionary()
        if addToDictionary() == False:
            continue
        else:
            exit()
        check_forChanges()
        if check_forChanges() == False:
            break
        else:
            continue
```

But I expect to be able to run this program until the user decides to quit. Also I expect the single while loop to call  both of my functions but only when necessary.

Comment: To summarize, please post a *minimal* example and question.

Comment: `addToDictionary()
check_forChanges()`

obviously needs a while loop

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is creating the while loop and to make it call the first function and run it but when you have no more items to add I need it to call the next function and makes sure you don't need to change any values of currently existing items. And then when the exit command is put in it exits the while loop and the program quits. I can't figure out how to make the while loop determine the first function is over and to call the next one.

It sounds like you want to keep adding to the dictionary until the user says "nothing more to add" and then checks the values until the user quits. That would look something like:

```
while addToDictionary(): pass
while check_forChanges(): pass
```

You'd have to modify your existing functions to False when the current action is complete and to call `sys.exit()` when the user asks to quit. Although I don't think you need to ask for quitting -- if they don't want to add or check, then they're done and the loops have terminated.

Do you ever want the user to add to the dictionary after check_forChanges is called? If yes, but you still want to enforce adding is done, then checking, then maybe more adding, you want a loop around the whole thing:

```
keep_looping = True
while keep_looping:
    while addToDictionary(): pass
    while check_forChanges(): pass
    keep_looping = askToContinue()
```